# Question on graphic designer positions in which one needs to know even HTML and CSS

Tags: css, html

About graphic designer positions where it needs to know HTML and CSS, what are all the projects one needs to be able to do with HTML and CSS in order to be employable?

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly broad question and will most likely be closed due to that.

But to provide a *general, broad* list of some tasks....

- Add images or text to a web page
- Create a landing page
- Create an HTMl email
- Adjust or correct existing web site(s), landing page(s), emails
- Understand what is and is not possible via HTMl/CSS when designing web content

This is merely a short list. Any employment position may have more specific needs.

Realize your question is akin to asking *"What are all the things you can do with Photoshop?"* the list is likely endless. Each employment position may only require a targeted set of skills, but what *is* possible is vast.

With HTML/CSS you either know it or you don't. It doesn't have quite the breadth of scope of image editing. If you know and understand HTML/CSS there is typically few things you *can't* do in relation to those markup languages.